# VBA: Refreshing Pivot Tables as Sheet Opens

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Pivot Tables on a sheet that I'd like to have automatically refreshed when the sheet is selected.  The Pivot Tables have been named "Order Detail-No Common Names" and "Master Table".  The code for the first table works but errors on the second table.  "Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error".  Does anyone have any idea as to why this may be?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Worksheets("TRANSLATION-Eligible Product").PivotTables("Order Detail-No 
Common Names").PivotCache.Refresh

Worksheets("TRANSLATION-Eligible Product").PivotTables("Master 
Table").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: You say it errors. What is the error?

Comment: "Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Ugly. Are you certain that you have the pivot table name correct (perhaps there is a space hanging out at the end of the name that isn't visible)? Is this pivot table located in the same worksheet that this `Worksheet_Activate()` event is located? Does it work if you remove the first refresh statement?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you spelled your sheet name and pivot tables right?

Comment: @JNevill I think he must have a misspelling - I believe even if this sub is located in another sheet's module, it will still run fine, no?

Comment: @dwirony I agree. I think a misspelling is the only thing that is going to cause this error. I was thinking, if it's the same worksheet, then the pivottable object doesn't need to be qualified by the `Worksheets()` object potentially eliminating another change to typo.

Comment: It's very odd, I've renamed the table and checked for typos several times.  Can't for the life of me figure this out.  The first PivotTables works and the code is in the correct sheet

Comment: @oryan5000 when you get the error, click debug and hover your arrow over each name (worksheets and pivot tables) and see which one says 1004

Comment: I figured it out.  Excel didn't like the second PivotTable because their was a blank row ahead of the column headers